# How to migrate AFNetworking 1.x to 2.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I'm trying to migrate AFNetworking version 1.x to 2.x.

In the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide), `AFHTTPClient.m` is separated to `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` & `AFHTTPSessionManager` but I can't find `AFHTTPClient registerHTTPOperationClass:` in either `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

What function can substitute for `registerHTTPOperationClass:`?

Comment: I believe you would just set the appropriate `responseSerializer` for `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. For example, `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]` or whatever. If that's not clear, perhaps expand your question with more details (or actual code sample) of how you're currently using `registerHTTPOperationClass` and describe precisely what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: that you pasted link of AFN 2.0 well contain well information about it you just need to read and try to understand what is mention into documentation. Do not find Example code just try your self.

Comment: have you asked yet the author of the `AFNetworking`, perhaps?

Comment: Please include your solution in your question, so others can benefit as well.